# React Closing dropdown menu on selecting a list item or clicking outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown menu made in my react js , What i want is when i click on any list items i want it to get it closed or also even if i click anywhere outside it the dropdown menu should close by itself  (and then opens up again on click ofcoss)

here is my code below for it

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TripTypeDropdown = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([
    { tripType: "One Way", value: 1 },
    { tripType: "Return", value: 2 },
    { tripType: "Multi- City", value: 3 },
  ]);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({
    tripType: "One Way",
    value: 1,
  });
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    console.log("toggle");
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const selectItemFromList = (index) => {
    console.log("select kiya");
    const itemSelected = values[index];
    console.log(itemSelected);
    setSelectedItem(itemSelected);
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  };
  const getActiveClassName = (item) => {
    if (selectedItem) {
      if (item.tripType == selectedItem.tripType) return "active";
      else return "";
    }
  };
  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {console.log(selectedItem)}
      <div
        onBlur={() => toggleDropdown()}
        onFocus={() => toggleDropdown()}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        <span className="custm-dropdown" >
          {selectedItem.tripType}
        </span>
        {isOpen && (
          <div className={`dropdown-modal sm-modal ripple`}>
            <ul>
              {values.map((item, index) => (
                <li
                  className={getActiveClassName(item)}
                  onClick={() => selectItemFromList(index)}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {item.tripType}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TripTypeDropdown;
```

The issue i am facing is when i am clicking the list items , my dropdown closes and then never opens up again. Hope someone helps me out.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
//import the following modules 
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

//create constant reference to the useRef();
const menuRef = useRef();

// create state to hold the state of your menu
// with a default state of close / flase
const [menuOpen,setMenuOpen] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {

        // Bind the event listener
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClicks);
          return () => {
            // Unbind the event listener on clean up
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClicks);
        };

    }, [menuOpen]);


//create a function in your component to handleOutsideClicks
const handleOutsideClicks =(event)=>{
  if(menuOpen&& menuRef.current && !menuRef.current.contains(event.target)){
      setMenuOpen(false);
   };
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` for this.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

const TripTypeDropdown = (props) => {

   const dropDownRef = useRef(null);

...


  const toggleDropdown = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.target !== dropDownRef.current)
       setIsOpen(false);//if clicked element (target) not the drop down close it
    else
       setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

...

<div    onClick={toggleDropdown}
        onBlur={(e) => toggleDropdown(e)}
        onFocus={(e) => toggleDropdown(e)}
        tabIndex="0"
      >
```